# how to write on sd card in android

Tags: android, sd-card

i am trying to backup sms on my sd card and its working but there is one problem when i am taking a backup its remove the previous stored file. but i want to keep all files on my sdcard. i am using this code

```
    backup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backup);
    backup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            backupSMS();
        }
             public ArrayList<String> smsBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
                String smsFile = "SMS"+".csv";



        private void backupSMS() {
            smsBuffer.clear();
            Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                    mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                            "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
            //startManagingCursor(cursor1);
            String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body",
                    "type" };
            if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
                String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
                Log.d("Count",count);
                while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {

                     String messageId = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[0]));

                     String threadId = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[1]));

                    String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                    String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                    String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                    String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[5]));
                    String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[6]));



                    smsBuffer.add(messageId + ","+ threadId+ ","+ address + "," + name + "," + date + " ," + msg + " ,"
                            + type);

                }           
                generateCSVFileForSMS(smsBuffer);
            }               
        }


         private void generateCSVFileForSMS(ArrayList<String> list)
        {

            try 
            {
                String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + smsFile;
                FileWriter write = new FileWriter(storage_path);

                write.append("messageId, threadId, Address, Name, Date, msg, type");
                write.append('\n');
                write.append('\n');


                for (String s : list)
                {
                    write.append(s);
                    write.append('\n');
                }
                write.flush();
                write.close();
            }

            catch (NullPointerException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Nullpointer Exception "+e);
                 //  e.printStackTrace();
             }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
    });
```

please help me i new to android . thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean that you want several backups, in which case could you give all your backups different names (maybe using the current time) and then save in a folder named 'smsbackups' or something then to do a restore just add all files in that folder to a list and the user selects which file to restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correcty your SMS.csv file is being over-written and you would like to keep adding additional files instead of over writing this file.

The line

`String smsFile = "SMS"+".csv";`

needs to be changed to something like

```
String smsFile = "SMS-" + SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() + ".csv";
```

This should create a new backup file each time.

Comment: wow great its working. thank you from bottom of my heart. but i have still a problem its not making a folder on SD card please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't post code as a comment to what you asked for creating a directory.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
    "/" + getPackageName() + 
    "/SMS-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + 
    ".csv");

if(file.mkdirs()) {
    // your code here for writing the file
    // your file is now at /sdcard/your.apps.package.name/sms-currenttime.csv
}
```

This should create a file at /sdcard/your.apps.package.name/sms-currenttime.csv